# assignment of observations to known size classes

Tags: multiclass-classification

Assume I have some observations and I want to predict their classes. For each observation my classification algorithm spits out probabilites for each class. Now assume I know exactly what distribution my prediction has to have. For example I know that 20 of my observations have to be in class 1, 15 in class 2 and so on. What is the best way to assign my observation based on their probabilities of belonging to a class. Does this problem have a name?

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially model this Information in form of a Prior, depending how you proceede with modelling. Check out [bayesian statistics](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bayesian_statistics)